# Bind a double to Datagrid column MaxWidth property

Tags: silverlight, binding, datagrid, ivalueconverter

I have a datagrid whose columns I would like to set the MaxWidth property of through binding. I have a converter to change 'binding' to 'double', but the converter never gets hit, the app stops on a xaml error: 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Double'. When I use the converter on other properties outside of the datagrid MaxWidth property then it works fine. Why does this not work?

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Converter:DoubleConverter x:Key="ConverterForDoubles" />
</Grid.Resources>

<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Task ID" Binding="{Binding TaskId}" 
MaxWidth="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, Path=TaskIdColumnMaxWidth,
Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ConverterForDoubles}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this to help with binding to setters: [Setting Value Binding Helper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/07/one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

DataGridTextColumn.MaxWidth is not a dependency property, so you cannot bind to it.

It is  just complaining about the presence of `"{Binding...}"` when it expected a double value to be parsed from the XAML.

Solutions include adding attached properties or subclassing the DataGridTextColumn and adding a Dependency property that does set the MaxWidth when it is set.

Comment: Is that not what a converter is supposed to do- convert from a binding to whatever you need?

Comment: No. Afraid not. Converters just convert between different types of values. The target must be a dependency property for it to be settable  via `SetValue` (which is what happens behind the scenes after the converter returns).